# Mathematica to LaTeX php

Tags: php, latex, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to get LaTeX out of Mathematica code?

I have to possible inputs:

1.

```
Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[List[StyleBox["3", Rule[ScriptLevel, 1]], 
   RowBox[List["(", "\[NoBreak]", GridBox[List[List["19", "3"],
   List["14", "2"]], Rule[RowSpacings, 1], Rule[ColumnSpacings, 1],
     Rule[RowAlignments, Baseline], Rule[ColumnAlignments, Center]], 
   "\[NoBreak]", ")"]]]], TraditionalForm]], "Output", List[], 
   Rule[PageWidth, 500], Rule[Magnification, 1], Rule[CellMargins,
   List[List[0, 0], List[0, 0]]], Rule[ShowCellBracket, False],
   Rule[FontFamily, "Bitstream Charter"], Rule[FontSize, 14],
   Rule[NumberSeparator, "\[ThinSpace]"]]
```

2.

```
{{19, 3}, {14, 2}}
```

Any idea how to get the LaTeX expression?

Comment: On a cell-by-cell basis, you can follow the guidelines in [convert Mathematica LaTeX to regular LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61054/5764). For including an entire notebook in LaTeX, perhaps consider using [Mathematica notebook into LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173476/5764).

Comment: I don't want to convert it inside Mathematica. A PHP or JS solution would be nice :)